# PHP Sessions Expiring Unexpectedly

Tags: php, session

I'm at a loss here.  I've got a specific group of users upstairs whose sessions seem to expire completely randomly.  It's not just when they leave the site sitting for a while, it can expire while they're browsing around.  For me and most of our users everything works just fine.  It's not a browser issue, we've got people in FF and all IE versions that both function correctly, and people in FF and IE that don't work.

My `gc_maxlifetime` is at `43200` and the garbage collection is a crazy low `1/1000` (not that that should matter). Is it possible there's something else running on the server that's randomly deleting some of our sessions?  What should I check?  That still wouldn't explain why only this specific group seems to be affected.

I have a few Session settings that are different from the default:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 43200
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
session.use_only_cookies = Off
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
```

The first three I'm not worried about, but could the last two be causing this behavior?  I don't actually ever send cookies through the URL, so I have no good reason for having use_only_cookies off.  I have no guarantees that the misfits who made this app before I got here didn't exploit the `bug_compat_42` thing to set session variables, but again, I would expect an issue with that to be less random.

Edit:

On further investigation, I've found that the Session is not being destroyed at all, but the end-user is getting a new session ID.  The old session still exists intact on the server, but a new one is randomly started while they're browsing.

Comment: One of two things is happening: the session file on the server is being deleted, or the session cookie is expiring.  I'd try to isolate a case of one or the other happening, and then work from there.

Comment: I've determined that it's not the session being deleted.  How can I check whether the cookie is expiring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here turns out to be that their browser was setting the session cookie to expire prematurely.  I've solved the issue with this dirty, dirty hack that you should never have to use, ever.  I'm not proud of this, but if this shines some light on anything feel free to let me in:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    if ($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] != "") {
        setcookie("PHPSESSID", $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"], time()+43200, "/", ".mydomain.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which browsers were being affected by this issue, we are seeing something similar with some users using ie10 only..

Comment: Very similar code is the most popular note for session_set_cookie_params on the php site. It seems like something you have to do to get things to work correctly. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657

Comment: I've had the same issue as you but on paid hosting. I could not figure out what could cause premature expiration so I did it similarly to your way. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a little more information about your set up?

My first thought would be that there is something randomly cleaning out your temporary files directory.  If you're using a standard LAMP set up, PHP will be storing the session data files into /tmp.  If they're getting deleted from there by a cleaning process, you'd lose your sessions.

Edit:  I'm re-thinking this now.  If only a specific group of users is affected, that makes it much less likely.

How about cookie settings?  I'd make sure that these people aren't using something like a dynamic proxy, and that your cookies are being set for the root domain of your site.  Is it possible they might have some privacy-cleaning software such as CCleaner set up as a scheduled task that might be removing their cookies?

I'd get up there on one of their computers and throw Firebug onto one of the Firefox machines and examine the HTTP requests to see if the cookies are being sent properly.

Comment: As I said, I've considered this option but I don't think this would produce the behavior that I'm getting.  If something were cleaning out the sessions I would expect everyone to be simultaneously logged out.  Instead I've got only a small group of people being logged out randomly.

What other information about the set up would be helpful?

Comment: You could verify all your session settings.  There's a list at http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php.

Answer (score 1):

I would install some http sniffer like [httpwatch](http://www.httpwatch.com) (paid but worth every penny) or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) (free) on those machines and see what's going on with the session cookies (I think it's PHPSESSID, but not sure). If the cookie is being deleted or changed in the middle of the session because of proxies, weird apache configuration or something, this would be the best way to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late. But just for some people who's having the same problem as well.

**[If you encrypt and decrypt your data]**

I've run with this issue and took me awhile to figure out what's the problem.
It keeps creating a new session ID for the same user.
Turns out that the encrypt data and the decrypt data is not the same.
The decrypt data returns with some additional white spaces.
Try check your data value when send and return from database or whatever storage you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my project a library is used to secure session, Sometime I observed that my session gets destroyed suddenly.

https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session/blob/master/SecureSession.php

First I want ton know what is the purpose of this library, we can to these setting from php.ini as well.

KEY_... a new created what is the use of this KEY.

When I use print_r inside open(), I get below sample result

```
Hqx_SecureSession Object
(
    [_debug:Hqx_SecureSession:private] => 
    [_key:protected] => 5ò™6žÝ°rIÐß'k Êii07ÀtCzªt@ü¸"‡ÄCžA¼ÿ£g{IP
    [_path:protected] => c:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\tmp\
    [_name:protected] => PHPSESSID
    [_ivSize:protected] => 16
    [_keyName:protected] => KEY_PHPSESSID
    [_cookieParams:protected] => Array
        (
            [lifetime] => 7200
            [path] => /
            [domain] => dev.autoquotes.insurance.com
            [secure] => 
            [httponly] => 1
        )

    [_sessionId:protected] => 
    [_logger:Hqx_SecureSession:private] => 
)
htq827r4rjh9ob05nhlqb8vmd5ai52djb0bd0l42vk9un26df541c:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\tmp
```